# 30 amp wire trace

Tags: electrical

I have just moved in to a new home and there are two panels. 200 amp main and a 100 amp panel for the suite. Both panels have 30 am breakers for a dryer. but I only have one dryer plug in the laundry room. Both panels also have 40 amp breakers for kitchen ranges, and I have two ranges in the house. The question is how do I trace the 30 amp wire from suite panel to where ever it goes? Panel wires are clearly marked with white tape and description matches panel label. I've checked for exposed junction boxes in closets, garage and everywhere in the house. My thought is the wire is capped with marrets and terminates in a wall?? So, I need to trace wire from 30 amp breaker to where ever it terminates? The Fluke 2042 cable locator is not in the budget. A tool closer to the $150 price is an option. Most wire/cable locators do not work with on the larger amp service.

thank you.

Comment: You might be able to rent a cable tracer that injects a signal (with the breaker off)..  But I recommend you hire a qualified electrician.

Comment: It's against code to terminate something in a wall.  Every wire must terminate in an accessible junction box, nowhere is it written they must be connected to a receptacle or anything obvious.  Are there any 2-gang or surface-mount boxes in places that would be sensible for locating a dryer, A/C or water heater?  Bet the wires terminate there.  Pop the covers off and have a look-see.

Comment: thank you for the replies. I don't think I have ever bought a house that complies with all codes. I will check for the 2 gang boxes. Tomorrow, Thursday, I will pick up a tone generator. Thanks again for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a tone generator like the one described in [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/14515/33), to successfully trace lines in walls and ceilings. You should be able to find a similar product for less than $100.

Just remember that these things do not work on live circuits, so you'll have to shut the power off to the circuit first.